# Using a Rate as a Probability

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Can I use a rate for something as a probability that it will occur once?
For example, I have the rate of something occurring in a given mile of driving. Can I use that rate as the probability that it occurs once in a given mile?
My thought process is if I use a Poisson distribution and set the number of occurrences to 1, then I just get the initial rate. Sorry if that didn't make sense, I don't have much of a math background. Thanks!

Comment: In a Poisson distribution with rate $\lambda$, the probability the event will happen exactly once is $e^{-\lambda}\lambda$. This is (for $\lambda\ne 0$) different from $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Poisson process with rate $r$, the number of occurrences in an interval of length $L$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $rL$.
The probability of exactly one occurrence in this interval is then $
rL \exp(-rL)$.  This would be $r$ if $L \exp(-rL) = 1$.   If $r \le e^{-1}$, there will be exactly two such $L$ values.  If $r > e^{-1}$, there are none.

Comment: forgive me if I misinterpreted your answer, but I want to make sure I got it right. So an example would be that an event occurs with a rate of .025 per mile and the car travels 6 miles. The probability would then be $6*.025*exp(-.025*6)$? Why does it differ from the probability of it occurring in one mile multiplied by the number of miles?

Comment: Because the events (occurring in the first mile), (occurring in the second mile), ..., (occurring in the sixth mile) are not mutually exclusive.